# SearchView style disturbs Toolbar Style Actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-styles

**WHAT I NEED:** I need the action bar with **white text** like this one:

[image: Action bar with White Text]

And the SearchView Recent Query **Suggestions** customized like this one:

[image: Suggestions customized]

**PROBLEM:** I can do both of them, but I can not do them at the same time, when I set the title to white, the suggestions style dissapear. I'll show how I am handling this.

**SUGGESTIONS LAYOUT**

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView" >
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">@layout/item_suggestions</item>
</style>
```

**@layout/item_suggestions:** This is where I customize the layout of the suggestions items and it **WORKS** perfectly.

**ACTION BAR STYLE**

As my AppTheme is Light, my default title for the action bar and buttons are black. To override (white title and icons) I do the following:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ...
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar"/>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

**FINAL PROBLEM:** When I apply this theme for the action bar to get the white text and icons. BOWN, the theme for the SearchView suggestions does not work anymore. What would be a clever way to achieve both at the same time?

**WHAT I ALREADY TRIED**

I already tried to change the style of the action bar in styles.xml (looked for thousand of questions) but could not achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a **Dark ActionBar Style**, so its buttons, titles, subtitles will be white (as I want). And then I set this style to my action bar.

Then, I set the SearchView style inside the CustomActionBar style.

**WARNING:** If I set my searchViewStyle outside of the CustomActionBar it will not work, it must be inside the CustomActionBar style to work.

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
         .../>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
         .../>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```